# How to extract string using regex with space before or after

Tags: java, regex

in the following examples, I want to extract "Mywebsite.xx". How do I do it?

```
Search Mywebsite.de  ----> Mywebsite.de
Mywebsite.de durchsuchen ----> Mywebsite.de
Search Mywebsite.co.uk ----> Mywebsite.co.uk
Mywebsite.co.uk something ----> Mywebsite.co.uk
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
String mydata2 = "Mywebsite.de durchsuchen";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Mywebsite(.*?)").matcher(mydata2);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: @g00se Not really, that would grab ALL of the second input.  It needs to end on space or end-of-string.

Comment: Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(Mywebsite[^ ]*)").matcher(mydata2);

Comment: "(?:^|.*\\s)(Mywebsite\\S*)(?:\\s.*|$)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Mywebsite\.([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)`

```
public static void extractDomain(String domain){
  Pattern domainPattern = Pattern.compile("Mywebsite\.([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)");
  Matcher match = domainPattern.matcher(domain);
 System.out.println("Mywebsite"+ match.group(1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern match for the input array of possible strings. The first four strings will match.

```
String patternStr = "(\\s|^)mywebsite([.][a-z][a-z]){1,2}(\\s|$)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String [] stringsToMatch = {
    "Mywebsite.co.uk xyz",
    "abc Mywebsite.co.uk",
    "abc Mywebsite.co.uk xyz",
    "Mywebsite.co.uk",
    "Mywebsite.co.uk.us",
    "Mywebsite"
};

for (String str : stringsToMatch) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    System.out.println(str);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("    " + str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("    No match");
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern also matches the following strings: `"Mywebsite.de"`, `"abc Mywebsite.de"`, `"Mywebsite.de xyz"` and `"abc Mywebsite.de xyz"`.

Comment: The `substring` also captures a leading and/or trailing space. So, apply the String class's `trim` method on the extracted string: `str.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()),trim()`

Answer (score 0):

To find the domain name from a string you can use regex like

`(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+`

This  program will capture list of domain from your string

```
public static List<String> extractDomainNames(String input) {
        List<String> domainNames = new ArrayList<>();
        String domainNamePattern = "(?:http[s]?://)?(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(domainNamePattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            domainNames.add(matcher.group());
        }
        return domainNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex: `Mywebsite\.[^\s]+`

```
String input = "Mywebsite.de durchsuchen";
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("Mywebsite\.[^\s]+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(input);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

See regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/xRriE9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Used regex:

```
"\\bMywebsite\\S+"
```

See regex in context and testbench, below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(
            "Search Mywebsite.de",
            "Mywebsite.de durchsuchen",
            "Search Mywebsite.co.uk",
            "Mywebsite.co.uk something"
    );

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bMywebsite\\S+");
    for (String input : inputs) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Mywebsite.de
Mywebsite.de
Mywebsite.co.uk
Mywebsite.co.uk
```

Comment:

```
Used Pattern:
\b  A word boundary
\S  A non-whitespace character: [^\s]
```

Read more about Pattern here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Other tools for testing regex:
https://regex101.com/